# Accessing User Profile from Facebbook

Tags: iphone

i have problem when user login then i want to show the user profile data in my UIView.
How can i access user profile from facebook when user gets login?

anyone suggest some solution would be great.

Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to implement their Facebook Connect method. Start out on Facebook's own developer wiki here:

http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Facebook_Connect_for_iPhone

Comment: I'm not too familiar with this yet. You might want to start with their Users.getInfo API:

http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Users.getInfo

There's a reference under the discussions tab of that wiki page that suggests it'll work from the iPhone SDK too.

Comment: This video has more details on how to make a FQL request to get user details, at around the 3rd minute: http://vimeo.com/3616452.